# Remove duplicate records from table, leaving one copy

Tags: mysql, duplication

I have inherited a MySQL table from one of my colleagues, and am in need of a little advice.

The table has the following structure:

```
| PHONE_NO   | ACC_NO | GET_MAIL | DATETIME_CRE         | INT_ACC | MAIL |
| 0113313313 | 000001 |   YES    | 2003-01-01 19:00:00  | 9000001 | N/A  |
```

There is no primary key, as the table was not created with one. I cannot recreate the table as:

1. It would take far too long to complete (over 2 million records and counting)
2. This is a `mission critical` table, meaning taking it down would result in my client losing money for the duration.

I need to be able to remove duplicated rows from the table with a query, without inserting a primary key. "Duplicated" in this sense refers to all columns within the row being identical to another row.

---

**EDIT**
This is the result of `show create table` query, as requested by  ypercube;

```
CREATE TABLE `callerQue` (
  `PHONE_NO` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACC_NUMBER` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GET_MAIL` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATETIME_CRE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_ACC` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MAIL` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this would work in mysql since i am a MSSQL-dba but you could add an identity column -> auto_increment.
This would make all rows unique.
Then you could do a group by on duplicate records and select the highest ID for example. This way you will only delete one row. 
Repeat this until no more duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

My question is, what would the overhead be for creating an auto-incremented column to a table with 4.5M rows?

Comment: After some persuasion, I have rebuilt the table with a PK now

Comment: How long did it take?

Comment: Given the limited usable resources (needs an upgrade) it took around 20 minutes. 3 days if you count arguing the need for a primary key to the client.